# Submit a form in Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a small application with a table and a form, nothing fancy. I want to be able to click on one specific row and delete/modify the information. I managed to do this using Richfaces but now I have to duplicate this functionality using Spring Framework.
I render a table row in this fashion:

```
    <form:form action="del.htm" commandName="movie">
 <td><form:hidden path="movieName"/>${movie.movieName}</td>
 <td><form:hidden path="year"/>${movie.year}</td>
 <td><form:hidden path="length"/>${movie.length}</td>
 <td><form:hidden path="category"/>${movie.category}</td>
 <td><form:hidden path="actors"/>${movie.actors}</td>
 <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" /><input type="submit" value="Modify"/></td>
    </form:form>
```

The action specified is mapped to a Controller that returns ModelAndView to render the page back. The function coresponding to deletion is called correctly but I *don't receive the movie* object so I can delete it from the database with Hibernate based on its id. If anyone has an idea of how to send the movie object I would be happy to hear it.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I added a snippet from my HTML in the message.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the movie id to the form?

```
 <td><form:hidden path="id"/>${movie.id}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like

```
 <td><a href="deleteMovie/${movie.id}"><spring:message code="label.delete"/></a></td>
```

then in your controller you should have a method with the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/deleteMovie/{id}")
public String removeMovie(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

    movieService.removeMovie(id);

    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

in order to pass the movie object to form you need to put your movie object to a map inside the method that causes your jsp to be rendered. so for example

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String selectMovie(Map<String, Object> map) {
    //PicasawebService myService = new PicasawebService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");

    map.put("movie", movieService.getMovie(id);


    return "movieDetails";
}
```

where movieDetails is the url pattern that makes your jsp with the form you showed us to be rendered.

i hope it helps..